# Is it possible to set color and size attributes of programmatically created radio buttons?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

In an activity java file, we created radio buttons dynamically in a for loop to display when the activity is run. However, because they are dynamically created, we are am unable to edit their properties (such as color, text size, etc) as in a typical xml file. How can we set such properties (color, size, etc...) programmatically?

```
public void PrintGames(ArrayList<String> games,String league ) {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_api_connection_test);
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
    RadioGroup rg2 = new RadioGroup(this);
    rg2.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    //ArrayList<RadioButton> buttons = new ArrayList<RadioButton>();


    for (int i = 0; i < games.size(); i++) {

        RadioGroup rg = new RadioGroup(this);
        rg.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        RadioButton button = new RadioButton(this);
        RadioButton button2 = new RadioButton(this);
        button.setText("Home");
        button2.setText("Away");
        button.setId(View.generateViewId());
        button2.setId(View.generateViewId());
        TextView textbutton = new TextView(this);
        rg.addView(textbutton);
        rg.addView(button);
        rg.addView(button2);
        textbutton.setText("" + games.get(i));
        rg2.addView(rg);
    }

    layout.addView(rg2);


    if (games.isEmpty()) {
        TextView nogames = new TextView(this);
        nogames.setText("No Games today");
        layout.addView(nogames);
    } else {
        Button submit = new Button(this);
        submit.setText("Submit");
        layout.addView(submit);
        //on click listner
        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Store(rg2,league);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I found some threads saying its not possible for radio buttons and there was suggestions to create vector asset drawables, but many of those threads are outdated (2011), and I have a feeling its possible now with the advanced studio we have.

Comment: Yes. Look through the API for RadioButton and its superclasses, esp. TextView. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioButton or https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/radiobutton/MaterialRadioButton

Comment: @Jerry101 wish there is a more concrete example. I see clickables, checkable, etc... but not regarding color or size. for example, once I have this, then what? `public RadioButton (Context context, 
                AttributeSet attrs, 
                int defStyleAttr, 
                int defStyleRes)`

Comment: After `RadioButton b = new RadioButton(...)` you can do `b.setChecked(true)`, `b.setTextAppearance(resId)`,`b.setTextColor(fgColor)`, `b.setTextSize(14F)`, `b.setBackgroundColor(bgColor)`. If you type `b.set` into the Android Studio editor, it will show the possible completions.

Comment: @Jerry101 Thanks Jerry, Ill try it out